# How to detect with Kinect that a person has turned to it with his/her back?

Tags: c#, kinect

I have written a program that takes SkeletonFrames from 4 different Kinects and merges them into one complete Skeleton with no inferred or untracked joints. 
The aim of my program is to track the person turning around, however in this case the Kinect is not capable to track the person's back and assume that the person is facing the Kinect.
How could I solve this issue?

Comment: Good question!
My first thought was to try and find the face, and if no face is found assume that they're looking the other way. But I saw that finding faces is seen as an "expensive" action. But might be an idea to try out?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj130970.aspx

Comment: I don't think you can see if the user is facing the kinect or not. The human back and front look pretty much the same as a skeleton. What you could do is have the user give the kinect a starting point (for example have the user face kinect 1 and push a button so the system knows a starting position). After that you could track a users arms/legs or analyzing the movement of his head to figure out what direction hes turning. There are some frameworks for that here: https://github.com/kylemcdonald/ofxHeadPoseEstimator and here https://github.com/ofTheo/kinectArmTracker